# NodeMCU http calls failing

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to communicate between 2nodemcu v2, standalone everything works fine - webserver, api etc. but when I start communicating between both devices only first API hit works thereafter it sometimes work and mostly fails.

libraries used:

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
```

Sample code which fails:

```
void notify(bool status1, bool status2)
{
  String URL = "http://192.168.0.14/status?status1=";
  URL += status1;
  URL += "&status2=";
  URL += status2;
  http.begin(URL);
  Serial.println(URL);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode > 0)
  {
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println("notified successfully");
    //Nothing to do actually
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error while notifying");
    Serial.println(httpCode);
  }
  http.end(); //Close connection
}
```

I am ending up with error in most cases.

***NOTE***: both my nodemcu run on local static IP

Comment: What error(s) do you end up with?

Comment: Httpcode -11, not getting anything apart from it

Comment: firewall on PC?

Comment: @Juraj No, its working some times and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: try to provide WiFiClient as the examples show. you use a deprecated api